# GridView inside Alert Dialog is not being populated

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have been trying to get a dialog to popup in my code with a Grid View, but the dialog is just showing up as a blank view. I can see the view is being created but not populated. Here is my code:

```
  public void chooseIcon(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
    gridView.setNumColumns(3);
    gridView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    gridView.setColumnWidth(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
    gridView.setVerticalSpacing(5);
    gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(5);
    gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
    IconImageAdapter adapter = new IconImageAdapter(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    builder.setTitle("Pick an icon");
    builder.setView(gridView);
    builder.show();
}
```

And here is the IconImageAdapter class:

```
public class IconImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
.....
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width/3, height/3));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    switch(position){
        case 0:{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle, mContext.getTheme()));
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle));
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle, mContext.getTheme()));
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle));
            };
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle, mContext.getTheme()));
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle));
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle, mContext.getTheme()));
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle));
            }
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle, mContext.getTheme()));
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle));
            }
            break;
        }
        case 5:{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle, mContext.getTheme()));
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle));
            }
            break;
        }
    }


    return imageView;
}
}
```

My drawable resources are xml files of circles that are used in other places in my app without issue.

Comment: I have one better solution for this question.First, Create one seperate xml layout(ex: gridview.xml) that contain your gridview designing and one activity class(GridView.java),In this class set gridview adapter and In AndroidManifest file register this GridView.java like this <activity
            android:name=".GridView"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" /> and In your Button click event set your Intent to redirect GridView.java activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate the view when you set it in the `builder.setView(gridView);`
Do it like this:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

builder.setView(layoutInflater.inflate(gridView.getId(), null));
```

this will work.